# Different ways to iterating through an array of objects javascript?

Tags: javascript

please ignore if this is a silly question to you. I just came up with my own solution to a problem, but I know its not a good solution and there are better smarter ways to do this, please answer if you have other solutions using javascript only.

Its asking to make a function to loop through an array of objects, and return the prop of the object if firstName matches the profile. Return some statements if firstName or prop provided to the function not found.

```js
var contacts = [
        {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intruiging Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    },
];
       
function lookUp(firstName, prop){

    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){  
            var n = parseInt(contacts.length);

        
            if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName)    {
            
                if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                    return contacts[i][prop];
                }
                else return "No such property";
                }
            else if (i === (n-1)) {
                return "No such contact";
            }
    }
}

console.log(lookUp("Sherlock", "likes"));
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use libraries?

Comment: look at Array.filter https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: No libraries, just plain javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change your `loopUp` method to this by using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
function lookUp(firstName, prop)
{
  var propValue = "No such contact";

  contacts.forEach( function( element ){ 
    if ( element.firstName == firstName ) 
    {
       propValue = element[ prop ] ? element[ prop ] : "No such property"; 
    }
  } );
  return propValue;
}
```

Also, just as @Amadan has mentioned rather than return error messages, throw an [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) back which you will need to catch in the calling method.

```
try 
{
   lookUp();//making call here
}
catch(e)
{ 
   console.error( e );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `contacts.length` is an integer, not a string, so `parseInt` is unnecessary.
- You don't actually need the `else if`: you can just put it outside the loop, because if the contact exists, you would have exited the function already. This also makes `n` unnecessary, and the first point moot.
- In general, it is a bad idea to return error messages, unless they are clearly distinguishable as error messages (see [semipredicate problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semipredicate_problem)); those should be thrown as exceptions, or at least returned as non-values `null`/`undefined`; or when you ask for `lookUp('Adolf', 'favouriteSoup')`, you might think the soup is called `"No such contact"`. However, if the task you were given was to return the error message, I don't suppose there's anything you can do about it.

Comment: I agree. Raising exception is way better practice. If the property value is `No such contact` it would be very ridiculous and unable to differentiate between valid and invalid output.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to split the two wanted functions to two functions.

1. Get all objects with a given key/value pair `lookUp(a, k, v)`
2. Get only one key from the array of object `getKey(a, k)`

```js
function lookUp(a, k, v) {
    return a.filter(function (b) {
        return b[k] === v;
    });
}

function getKey(a, k) {
    return a.map(function (b ) {
        return k in b? b[k]: 'no property ' + k;
    });
}

function print(o) {
    document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(o, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
}

var contacts = [{ "firstName": "Sherlock", "lastName": "Holmes", "number": "0487345643", "likes": ["Intruiging Cases", "Violin"] }, { "firstName": "Akira", "lastName": "Laine", "number": "0543236543", "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"] }, { "firstName": "Harry", "lastName": "Potter", "number": "0994372684", "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"] }, { "firstName": "Kristian", "lastName": "Vos", "number": "unknown", "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"] }];

print(lookUp(contacts, 'firstName', 'Sherlock'));
print(getKey(lookUp(contacts, 'firstName', 'Sherlock'), 'likes'));
```